# Etimologia dell'espressione "è stato un fiasco"

Tags: phrase-origin

Si tratta di un modo di dire molto diffuso, anche, ad esempio, in [inglese](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/fiasco), per indicare un fallimento. Sapreste dirmi qual è la sua origine?

Comment: L'uso in inglese viene direttamente dall'italiano, attraverso il linguaggio dell'opera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* di Carlo Lapucci (Garzanti-Vallardi, 1979), confermando che l'origine è incerta, ricorda due congetture:

> La metafora è presa probabilmente dal linguaggio dei soffiatori di vetro che, quando sbagliano nel fare un recipiente al quale intendevano dare una bella forma, finiscono col trovarsi nelle mani una vescica o una grossa bolla di vetro simile a un fiasco.
>   Il solito aneddoto vorrebbe che l'origine del detto fosse fatta risalire a Domenico Biancolelli che, nel secolo XVII, usava improvvisare, nelle vesti di Arlecchino, un monologo prendendo lo spunto da una cosa qualsiasi. Una sera scelse un fiasco, ma non ebbe successo.
>   L'origine comunque è incerta.

Answer (score 4):

Il termine, secondo [questo blog](http://www.sapere.it/sapere/strumenti/domande-risposte/di-tutto-un-po/perche-si-dice-fare-fiasco.html), proviene dal gergo teatrale:

> Il modo di dire "fare fiasco" nasce da un fatto accaduto parecchio
>   tempo fa in un teatro fiorentino, dove un artista famoso ogni sera si
>   esibiva in simpatici monologhi, che condivideva con oggetti a cui si
>   rivolgeva adoperando parole e smorfie divertenti.  Una sera però
>   decise di esibirsi in un monologo portandosi come compagno di scena un
>   tipico fiasco da vino; invece di divertire il pubblico però, l’artista
>   lo annoiò così tanto che questo reagì e in cambio iniziò a fischiarlo
>   a più non posso.
>
> Da allora è rimasto questo modo di dire “far fiasco”, quando si
>   deludono completamente le aspettative di qualcuno, senza rendersene
>   conto fino al momento dei fischi o delle aspre critiche.

Mentre per [Hoepli](http://Il%20detto%20ha%20origine%20incerta,%20bench%C3%A9%20esista%20anche%20in%20francese,%20in%20inglese%20e%20in%20tedesco.%20Alcuni%20vogliono%20che%20alluda%20ai%20soffiatori%20di%20vetro,%20che%20se%20sbagliano%20l'operazione%20si%20trovano%20alla%20fine%20della%20canna%20in%20cui%20soffiano%20una%20bolla%20informe%20simile%20a%20un%20fiasco%20invece%20della%20sagoma%20voluta.%20Altri%20lo%20fanno%20risalire%20a%20un%20episodio%20della%20carriera%20di%20Domenico%20Biancolelli,%20un%20attore%20comico%20del%201600,%20che%20nelle%20vesti%20di%20Arlecchino%20si%20esibiva%20improvvisando,%20prendendo%20spunto%20da%20una%20cosa%20qualsiasi.%20Si%20dice%20che%20una%20sera%20abbia%20scelto%20come%20argomento%20un%20fiasco,%20e%20gli%20manc%C3%B2%20il%20successo.):

> Il detto ha origine incerta, benché esista anche in francese, in
>   inglese e in tedesco. Alcuni vogliono che alluda ai soffiatori di
>   vetro, che se sbagliano l'operazione si trovano alla fine della canna
>   in cui soffiano una bolla informe simile a un fiasco invece della
>   sagoma voluta. Altri lo fanno risalire a un episodio della carriera di
>   Domenico Biancolelli, un attore comico del 1600, che nelle vesti di
>   Arlecchino si esibiva improvvisando, prendendo spunto da una cosa
>   qualsiasi. Si dice che una sera abbia scelto come argomento un fiasco,
>   e gli mancò il successo.